# Why is JSON disregarding the escape?

Tags: json

JSON is disregarding the backslashes on line 3. I want whatever is between double quotes from line 3 to 18 as a string.

This is my JSON code:

```
{
    "schema":
    "syntax = \"proto3\";
    message SearchRequest {
        float eventVersion = 1;
        string producedBy = 2;
        string asupSubject = 3;
        int64 sysSerialNo = 4;
        int64 systemId = 5;
        string rawAsupPath = 6;
        int64 completedTimestamp = 7;
        string sourceQueue = 8;
        .SearchRequest.addonattributes addOnAttributes = 9;
  message addonattributes {
    string asupSecureType = 1;
    string sesgFlag = 2;
        }
    }",
  "schemaType": "PROTOBUF"
}
```

This is the output received:

```
{
    "error_code": 400,
    "message": "Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 3, column: 27] (through reference chain: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.entities.requests.RegisterSchemaRequest[\"schema\"])"
}
```

Comment: Usually, you should not put a JSON inside a string. **Thus, the value of `syntax` should be a child JSON and not a string.** The following site gave a nice and easy to understand graphic of the syntax of a JSON : https://www.json.org/json-en.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its actually the linebreaks that are breaking it. Try this:

```
{
    "schema":
    "syntax = \"proto3\";\n    message SearchRequest {\n        float eventVersion = 1;\n        string producedBy = 2;\n        string asupSubject = 3;\n        int64 sysSerialNo = 4;\n        int64 systemId = 5;\n        string rawAsupPath = 6;\n        int64 completedTimestamp = 7;\n        string sourceQueue = 8;\n        .SearchRequest.addonattributes addOnAttributes = 9;\n  message addonattributes {\n    string asupSecureType = 1;\n    string sesgFlag = 2;\n        }\n    }",
  "schemaType": "PROTOBUF"
}
```

Note: This works for you're initial text here, if you have other special characters in the future they will need escaped accordingly.

Additional Note: As pointed out in the comment, storing child JSON not ideal and I suspect it will make the solution difficult to maintain.

Comment: Usually one should not store a child JSON as a string to begin with...  Your answer do fix the problem but it is not what I would generally recommand.

Comment: Yep, I agree, hence my note... I should have made that point clearer!